# Make a variable available in all controllers

Tags: php, laravel

I am not sure the title of the question is clear, so I will try to explain it in details.

I want to execute a piece of code in every controller automatically, assign the result to a variable that will be globally accessible everywhere.

So the code that need to be run will be like this:

```
function getLanguage() {
    session('lang') ? session('lang') : 'en';
}
$LANG = getLanguage();
```

In any controller I need to access that variable like this:

```
myModel::all($LANG);
```

Also in the view, it would be helpful to access that variable as well (if possible)

```
<div> User language: {{$LANG}}</div>
```

Is there any place where I can execute that piece of code automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a middleware
- Add new middleware to `App\Http\Kernel`s `$middleware` property, if you want it to  run on every request. You may also put into `$middlewareGroups` property's `web` key.
- Your middleware's handle method will be like this

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    Config::set('some-name.some-sub-name', session('lang') ?: 'en');

    return $next($request);
}
```

- You will be updating a config in your middleware. This config has to be set only in this middleware to prevent possible problems of shared global state. (it is also important to be unique)
- Then you can use it with `config('some-name.some-sub-name')`

Comment: Will it also be available in services? I'mg getting empty result for config variable.

Comment: it will be globally available for after the middleware is executed. You may try just one line below after you set it(in the middleware) by `dd`ing it. @Lamar

Comment: Actually it worked, it was my bad in the first place. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In your use-case, you should implement a global middleware which sets the locale as you wish

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Session\SessionManager;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;

class CheckLocale
{
    /**
     * The application instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application
     */
    protected $app;

    /**
     * The session manager instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Session\SessionManager
     */
    protected $sessionManager;


    public function __construct(Application $app, SessionManager $sessionManager)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $this->app->setLocale($this->sessionManager->get('lang', 'en'));

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

After setting it as a global middleware, you can access it wherever you need it from a controller or view

Controller

```php
public function foo(Application $app)
{
    $lang = $app->getLocale();
}
```

In a Blade view

```php
@inject('app', Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application::class)

{{ $app->getLocale() }}
```

For any other variable, you may directly use Laravel container

In a service provider `register` method:

```php
$this->app->singleton('lang', function ($app) {
    return $app['session']->get('lang', 'en');
});
```

And wherever else

```php
app('lang');
```

Comment: That looks great! But where should I put the middleware? Also if i need to specify a custom variable rather than the locale, how can I access it?

Comment: Append it to `$middleware` property of `App\Http\Kernel`. About your other question, you may use Laravel container, I edited my post to show you

Comment: Thank you very much, I like your way in calling app('lang') variable, but I am actually using it inside a service, in which app is not defined.

Comment: it is, you can use it wherever you are